# Calling foursquare userless api from the command line

Tags: api, oauth, foursquare, clientid

I have been successfully using foursquare's API with the `oauth_token` from the command line using wget. E.g.,

```
wget https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4510e899f964a52089391fe3?oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&v=20120327
```

With this command, I was able to obtain the response and parse the results.  However, since using the authentication token has a limit of 500 requests per hour (etc.) and since I am interested in userless access, I thought of using the `client_id` and `client_secret`.  However, whenever I am trying to call

```
wget https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4510e899f964a52089391fe3?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&v=20120327"
```

I get a Bad request.  Is it possible to do what I am trying ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that the userless access also have limits (5000 per hour), more info [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues)

The request you listed above should work, I just tested it, replacing the MY_CLIENT_ID with my  real id and the secret as well.
I know that **foursquare is case-sensitive to the request**, the client_id/secret should be uppercase.

The only thing I can think of that is creating your problem is a typo, check your data :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  Yes I know about the 5000 limit but it is 10 times more than with the token :) Hmm it is good at least to know that wget works with client_id/secret.  I will check on it more. Thanks.

Comment: A small comment on this, I think the 500 is 500 / user token, when the 5000 is 5000 per 'application token' (= id+secret). So basically if you have no problems with people authenticating with foursquare, then it should be the better option for you, however, if the user authentication is not required at all (=only venue information), then do not make your users authenticate, stay with the 'userless' access.